# PHP and PostgreSQL: Avoiding cross-site scripting and SQL injection attacks

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, insert, sql-injection

When inserting data into a PostgreSQL database through PHP, should I embed the data in a `sql INSERT` statement within the function `pg_query`, or would it be more secure to pass the data through an array into the `pg_insert` function?

My guess would be `pg_insert` since it's just inserting the data directly into the table rather than querying the table and then inserting it.

Please visit http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php for reference to these 2 functions.

Comment: XSS and SQL injection are two possibly unrelated issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid SQL injection, you want to call methods that accepts SQL parameters as method parameters. That way, your *SQL library* can make sure that the parameters are properly escaped. Never build your own SQL-statements by "appending" string-fragments. If you do, you are responsible for SQL-escaping the parameters. This is hard to get right.

Therefore, you should prefer `pg_query_params` (or `pg_insert`) over `pg_query`.

This is wrong (because *you* must remember to escape the $arg1-parameter. Which is hard.):

```
pg_query("INSERT INTO TABLE ... VALUES " . $arg1 . ";");
```

Right (because the smart guys at PostgresQL know how to escape your parameter):

```
pg_query_params("INSERT INTO TABLE ... VALUES $1", "FooBar");
```

Comment: You can even cast your parameters directly in your queries `SELECT … WHERE a_field = $1::int4`.